# Why the OpenTK(C#) based rendering to texture showed nothing

Tags: opentk, volume-rendering

My [project](https://github.com/ShannonZ/playground) aims to render to texture based on OpenTK (Version 3.0.1.0, C#). Most codes were translated from [this tutorial](https://github.com/opengl-tutorials/ogl/blob/master/tutorial14_render_to_texture/tutorial14.cpp) which using C++.

I just want to use an texture(int backfaceTex) in the default render frame (pass#1). The texture backfaceTex stores the rendering results in an offline frame buffer.   But when call the rendered buffer(pass#2), I can only see a black window right now. It seems that all elements of the backfaceTex  are zero. Why? There should be a colored cube on the screen.
[image: A correct image]

The code is short and simple, all relevant data/shaders were also attached for reproducing this issue. The private function Display() is the real rendering part.(2-pass rendering)
[image: render pipeline]

I want to know which part of my implementation is wrong? Any ideas are welcome.